# Казнить нельзя помиловать

Tags: обсуждение, вопросы, удаление-вопросов

Что делать с теми, кто спамит сообщество примерно однотипными вопросами, подходя к своей проблеме с разных сторон, как бы намекая на то, что проблему надо решить за автора, ибо автор ..? Кхм... Ибо автор не может её решить.

При этом, после того, как проблема решается, большинство вопросов, которые проблему решить не помогли, **удаляются из-за отрицательных оценок**, а вместе с ними **удаляются и хорошие ответы** конкретно по теме вопроса, лишь потому, что они не содержат в себе решение **настоящей проблемы** автора.

Comment: кстати, удалить вопрос, у которого есть ответ с положительным рейтингом, весьма проблематично.

Comment: @Grundy да и следует ли? кому-то может помочь. Лучше учиться на чужих ошибках. А вот за систематическое удаление на основном SO положен временный (а то и постоянный) suspend аккаунта, наверно, следует применять такую же практику

Comment: @Swift, на самом деле она и так применяется :-) Стараются же удалить не потому, что никому не помогает, а чтобы от минусов избавиться

Comment: @Grundy ы, а разве это так работает? А, они _думают_ что избавляются. Счетчик то навсегда остается.

Comment: @Swift, репутация откатывается. То есть, если был вопрос им накидали 10 минусов, то при удалении его - потерянная репутация вернется. _Счетчик то навсегда остается._ - вот тут не совсем понял какой счетчик

Comment: @Grundy у tackexchange есть глобальный счетчик репутации (по всем сайтам),на его основе может произойти блокировка или изменение статуса доверия (например, мне на всех сайтах по умолчанию давно уже поднимают репутацию за активность на английском stackoverflow и на сайте английского языка). Не думал, что он откатывается.

Comment: @Swift, там простая сумма по всем сайтам, где рейтинг больше 200 или что-то такое